# How to use the divine model checker?

Tags: c

I have been trying to use the [DIVINE4](https://divine.fi.muni.cz/index.html) model checker to verify a sample C program, but due to the conflicts in the provided tutorials I haven't had good results. 
Can you suggest any good sources that explains the steps clearly?
(I have thoroughly looked for this, but haven't found much)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIVINE [manual](https://divine.fi.muni.cz/manual.html) should cover most of the topics you would need. However, the examples are not updated to the newest version of DIVINE.

This can be fixed. Let's take, for example, the first example airlines.cpp. If you do the following changes:

1. Comment out #include "divine.h".
2. Replace all "__divine_choice" with "__vm_choose".
3. Replace "__divine_malloc" with "malloc"

You can execute the verification using:

```
divine/_build.release/tools/divine verify -std=c++11 airlines.cpp
```